# 4 hd in my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, partition, ssd, apfs

I have 4 hd in my MacBook Pro. Macintosh HD - system disk. But where did the 3 other disks come from and what to do with them?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only one SSD in your MacBook Pro. The main former CoreStorage/HFS+ volume and the Recovery HD were transformed/merged to an APFS container while upgrading to macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) though.

Here is the old partition scheme:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0:
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                       *120.5 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                    209.7 MB    disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           119.4 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD            650.0 MB    disk0s3
```

After converting it to APFS disk0s2 and disk0s3 are merged to disk0s2 as one physical volume (container). The container is split into various *volume disks*.
A boot disk APFS container usually provides four volumes with different roles:

- Preboot (which has no predecessor)
- a non specific one/multi-purpose (the former system volume)
- Recovery (the former Recovery HD)
- VM (which has no predecessor)

Only one (the former system volume) is visible in the Finder!

The sizes of the volumes can be adjusted dynamically by the system without user interaction.

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                       *120.5 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1        120.3 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                     +120.3 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            13.7 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 19.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                519.9 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk1s4
```

---

The app you are using probably shows the possible max size of each APFS volume disk and **not** the real allocated size. It's either not properly adapted to the new file system or it's on purpose.

To get the real sizes enter `diskutil list` or `diskutil ap list` in Terminal.app. To get more APFS sub-commands enter `man diskutil`.